# VS2017 is not recognizing that I installed .NET Core 2.0 Preview 1 on m machine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, dotnet-cli

I downloaded and installed the following on my Windows machine:
    https://github.com/dotnet/cli

In command line if I type:

```
dotnet --version
```

I see the following: 2.0.0-preview2-005905

How can I actually work with this in Visual Studio 2017? The templates still create 1.1 apps. How do I make sure 2.0.0 is my working runtime?

I changed the following in one of my projects:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

from 1.1 to 2.0

I keep getting Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>=2.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the preview version of VS 2017 to get it to work.  It won't work with your existing version of VS 2017.

[Announcing Net Core 2 Preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/10/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-1/)

[VS 2017 Preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/)

Comment: to be more specific, you should have VS2017 version 15.3 or higher AND install .NET Core 2.0 Preview 1 SDK. Someone already answered this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618678/use-visual-studio-2017-with-net-core-sdk-2-0