# .Net Standard 2.0 build fails on Teamcity

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity, .net-standard-2.0

I am converting a project to the new `.csproj` format and setting it up to target both netstandard2.0 and net45. It's working fine on my machine, but somehow fails on our build server when trying to build for netstandard2.0. The build for net45 runs without errors. Part of the log:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn\csc.exe <lots of parameters>
Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Serialization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BinaryFormatter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICloneable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am aware that these types did not exist prior to version 2.0, but it is unclear how it fails to find them. .Net Core 2.0 SDK seems to be installed on the build server, besides I tried running it with lower versions of the SDK and it explicitly told me to target a different version of the standard. As far as I know, since version 2.0 there's no need for explicit dependencies on the standard library in the project file.

What could be the reason of these errors?

We use an MsBuild script ran by Teamcity MsBuild build runner with ToolsVersion=15.0.

Comment: Is a NuGet restore executed prior to the msbuild call (e.g. `msbuild /t:Restore`)

Comment: Yes, we use a built-in MsBuild target `restore` on the solution file. It does all the work on a clean repo on my machine

Comment: does the "lots of parameters" include a reference to `netstandard.dll`? at least `ICloneable` should be defined in there

Comment: You should show your `.csproj` file content, so that we can see if you make the things right initially. For multiple target frameworks, you usually need conditional references, similar to my project file here, https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/SharpSnmpLib/SharpSnmpLib.csproj#L33

Comment: @MartinUllrich hmm, there is a lot of references like `reference:C:\Users\buildserver\.nuget\packages\system.runtime\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.5\System.Runtime.dll /`. Note the standard version. None says netstandard2.0, so that may point to the problem. But why does it use libraries for the older versions? Could it be because package restoration is done by msbuild, not by `nuget.exe`?

Comment: @LexLi it has a `<TargetFrameworks>` element saying `netstandard2.0;net45`. I do have a similar conditional reference for net45, but, as I said, netstandard2.0 seems to reference all of the standard library by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I seem to have figured the answer myself.

MsBuild runner uses SDK installed as part of Visual Studio to build, and VS only adds proper support for .NET Core 2.0 SDK in version 15.3. Some earlier version was installed on the build server. The errors were caused by it being unable to resolve the correct SDK and using dlls from the older versions instead. One of the parameters passed to the compiler (note the version of the standard): `reference:C:\Users\buildserver\.nuget\packages\system.runtim‌​e\4.3.0\ref\netstand‌​ard1.5\System.Runtim‌​e.dll /`.

One way to solve this would be to update Visual Studio to 15.3 on the build server. I got out with the workaround in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43625979/8733264).

Answer (score 1):

You can install only the Visual studio 2017 Build tools

(https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15